# Is it safe to return a const char * from a function that use a static std::string internally?

Tags: c++

I am looking at the following code ( simplified ) and ask myself how safe is it to use this `returnMsg` function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char *returnMsg(const char *msg)
{
    static std::string message;

    message = msg;

    return message.c_str();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *msg1 = returnMsg("Hello world");
    printf("msg1 = %p\n", msg1);
    cout << msg1 << endl;

    const char *msg2 = returnMsg("Good bye");
    printf("msg2 = %p\n", msg2);
    cout << msg2 << endl;

    cout << msg1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the output is :

```
msg1 = 0x23a6028
Hello world
msg2 = 0x23a6028
Good bye
Good bye
```

`msg2` is written twice and it's what i expected since the static message variable remains in memory during the lifetime of the program and there is no memory reallocation, so what is written at `msg1` address is replaced by the new content of `msg2`.

However if the size of `msg2` is bigger, there is an internal reallocation within `std::string message` variable and the output is :

```
msg1 = 0x1cc6028
Hello world
msg2 = 0x1cc6058
Good bye looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
Hello world
```

but I guess that there is no guarantee that `msg1` address will not be reused in the future, and so a new access to `msg1` content might eventually display something different and not coherent.

Does this function needs to be written differently to make it possible to use it without the limitations shown above?

Comment: what is the function actually supposed to do? As it stands you could replace `const char *msg2 = returnMsg("Good bye");` with `const char *msg2 = "Good bye";` and you would not need to deal with the problems you are having now

Comment: @tobi303 I can't speak for OP, but consider a slightly less minimal example where the function is called with a non-static string and where the pointer is used after that buffer no longer exists. This function would allow conveniently to extend the lifetime of such buffer by copying its contents to a static string... but only until the next time the function is called.

Comment: @user2079303 no offense, but thats speculation and I would consider such function as a decorated global just that it is worse than a global

Comment: @tobi303 speculation is exactly what it is :) But global state like this is hardly an unusual (anti) pattern. See for example `strtok` and `errno`. Global state indeed has limitations, which are the problem that OP has.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it safe to return a const char * from a function that use a static std::string internally?

Yes, that is safe.

But it is not safe to use that pointer after it has been invalidated, which is what the shown program does. The pointer will be invalidated by an assignment in a successive call to that function, if it reallocates. So, the pointer is safe only until the next call to the function (that would cause reallocation).

> Does this function needs to be written differently to make it possible to use it without the limitations shown above ?

The function has the described limitations, so of course it has to be written differently to not have those limitations.

The core problem of your approach is that you only have one static string, but want to store multiple strings while not throwing away any of the earlier ones. So, it seems that you need a whole bunch of static strings:

```
const char *returnMsg(const char *msg)
{
    static std::forward_list<std::string> messages;
    messages.emplace_front(msg);
    return messages.front().c_str();
}
```

While this works as you would expect, it is silly. Consider whether you really want to store all strings for the rest of the execution. If not, then static storage is not a solution.

Comment: NB. the pointer MAY get invalidated ,that is when a reallocation is needed during assign. When not ,it's safe (although not very wise).

Comment: @engf-010 I added qualification, to take that into account.

Answer (score 3):

The code above leads to *Undefined Behaviour*. Just look at [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) documentation:

> The pointer obtained from c_str() may be invalidated by:
>
> - Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
> - **Calling non-const member functions on the string**, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and
>     rend().

When you call [`operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) for the second time inside `returnMsg()`, `msg1` is invalidated and using it is *Undefined behaviour*.

Comment: NB. the pointer MAY get invalidated ,that is when a reallocation is needed during assign. When not ,it's safe (although not very wise).